# Uploading files in chunks with blueimp in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, blueimp, chunks

I try to put the plugin blueimp to my php application. My upload target is short films about 200MB. The problem is that when I set maxChunkSize to 1MB the plugin uploads a file of 977kb and I get:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token A.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with uploading files in chunks , this link helped me .

I think it should help you too .

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads